# change brightness ubuntu12.04LTS

Tags: ubuntu, screen-brightness

How to change brightness in Ubuntu 12.04?
I can't change it in Ubuntu, the screen is always working at the top brightness,
I tried to change it in the system setting but in vain, there is no change.
please give me a easy solution.

Answer (score 2):

Look here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1802755&page=3

Comment: Thank you.My laptop is AS5750G, I tried to change grub as instructed, but unfortunately I still can not change it .Is there another way?

Comment: i did as "Manyette" suggested, it worked!, now i can change the screen brightness, but i still cannot save the setting, i have to adjust the brightness after each new boot. But it is fine. Thanks for your post

Comment: You just happened to have an acer ?